# How to use XML data as variables in CSS?

Tags: html, css, xml, variables

I want to develop a display of data that cannot, for technical reasons, be put into a database, so XML seems to be my only solution so far. I need to display elements on an x/y axis graph, each one to be clickable and open a div containing further information. Imagine a list of fruits, to be displayed based on an x axis of crunchiness (0-100) and a y axis of greenness (0-100), then when clicked you can see nutritional information, photo, etc. (something a little [like this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble))

The XML would be something like this:

```
<fruit_list>
  <fruit>
    <name>Orange</name>
    <xaxis>7</xaxis>
    <yaxis>5</yaxis>
    <description>round and orange and not crunchy</description>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>Granny Smith apple</name>
    <xaxis>85</xaxis>
    <yaxis>90</yaxis>
    <description>round and green and crunchy</description>
  </fruit>
</fruit_list>
```

I was hoping that there would be a way to use the value of the x and y data in the XML to define the position of the elements in the CSS. I have to admit I haven't had much experience with XML, I have only ever used it to display data in simple tables. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You'll need some kind of intermediary to generate the CSS with your variables.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea of mine, but you could use different CSS classes for a custom range on the x&y axis.

For example, you could define that Range 90-100 (x) and 90-100 (y) has the class

```
.x90-100_y90-100{
    /*Your CSS comes here...*/
}
```

Range 90-100 (x) and 80-89 (y) has the class

```
.x90-100_y80-89{
    /*Your CSS comes here...*/
}

...
```

And so one.

Then you could asign the classes to the HTML elements (JS,PHP,etc) in the function where you create your HTML elements from the XML file.

Maybe this can help you :)